# A document must not include both a meta element with an http-equiv attribute

Tags: javascript, utf-8, meta-tags

My html pages all start by including just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> ...
```

And they validate fine at w3C, with the one utf-8 meta declaration.

But then I "save as" my DISPLAYED page that is shown on screen, and submit that to validation
(Purpose: trying to verify the Javascript generated HTML in the page)

And then validation catastrophically fails with this, and seemingly quits:

```
 Error: A document must not include both a meta element with an http-equiv attribute whose value is content-type, and a meta element with a charset attribute.

From line 3, column 68; to line 3, column 89

et=UTF-8"><meta charset="utf-8">↩<titl
```

I only include the one utf-8 meta, but seems as if Firefox browser is adding the second?
(and saving it with Chrome goes wild with dozens of errors in it)

The pages include nothing else but images and Google Ads
(which I suspected, but first deleting all the Google ads had no effect on the error, still there) (W3C cache has never seemed any issue when uploading the file from local disc).

So I conclude this error is erroneous somehow, or at least benign, but it does leave the question of if there is a way to validate the Javascript generated code?

And any explanation of the multiple UTF-8 error is certainly appreciated too.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't use `<head>` like you're supposed to. Browsers will fix up malformed html as best they can which is often not very good.

Comment: Thanks.  I remember some early HTML5 format instructions said HTML5 did not need head, and I also had the notion it was optional, and now I see some saying HTML5 calls it header. Nevertheless, I just now tried adding both forms (one at a time) and there was no change, no improvement.

Comment: I did some testing in Firefox and Chrome. When using "Save as" with the "HTML only" option, I get the original html. When using the "complete" option, it looks like the html is mangled for compatibility. I mentioned before that browsers will fix up malformed html. I suspect that need for compatibility overrides the need for spec compliant html.

Comment: I was using Save As as "complete", because "HTML only" is said to NOT include the CSS or Javascript files.  I have not tested that, but I specifically wanted to validate the generated HTML, more than the original HTML.

Comment: As far as the reported error, it is technically correct (Firefox adds `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`, essentially the same as `<meta charset="utf-8">`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)) but is of low severity. In practice, it usually doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps it doesn't matter.  W3C is silent after that, and I thought it just quit, but If I add an intentional error like a reversed </div> <div>, it does also diagnose that, as a stray end and an unclosed too.   So if silent, maybe I can assume my Javascript produced HTML that I can see is in there is also OK. That's progress for me, thank you.